# Apache: Missing folders rewritten to php-files

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a site with the url `http://localhost/my-site/`. A file called `test.php` exists on root, a folder named `test` does not exist.

When I open a link like `http://localhost/my-site/test/`, the file test.php is opened. Should it not give a 404 error instead? I have no .htaccess file doing any funny business. The rewriting seems to be done before any .htaccess file is being run, as a rewrite rule of `test/` does not match anything. A rewrite rule of `test.php` does however match.

I am using WampServer 2.2 with Apache 2.4.2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This sounds like a mod_negotiation/Multiviews issue.

In the appropriate place (say, in your vhost config, or in the htaccess file in `my-site`'s directory, include in the Options a - multiviews:

```
Options -Multiviews
```

Comment: Spot on! It was as easy as disabling Apache's mod_negotiation :)